# Decoding nested objects in JSON

Tags: json, swift

I'm trying to fetch some data using YouTube JSON API, JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
  "etag": "AVEF8yG4pQMKfzZjMyy1rfVtFXA",
  "pageInfo": {
    "resultsPerPage": 1
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#channel",
      "etag": "LpEHq7VFVl1gDbt97Gf4ObyFn0U",
      "id": "UCBJycsmduvYEL83R_U4JriQ",
      "statistics": {
        "viewCount": "2084223845",
        "commentCount": "0",
        "subscriberCount": "12100000",
        "hiddenSubscriberCount": false,
        "videoCount": "1272"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And here is my code:

```
import Foundation
struct StatResponse: Decodable {
    let items: Items
}
struct Items: Decodable {
    var statistics: Stats
}
struct Stats: Decodable {
    let subscriberCount: Double
}
enum APIError: Error {
    case wrongURL
    case decodingError
    case noData
}
extension URL {
    static func url() -> URL? {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=UCBJycsmduvYEL83R_U4JriQ&key=API_KEY") else {
            return nil
        }
        return url
    }
}
class StatService {
    func getStats(completion: @escaping (Result<Items?,APIError>) -> Void) {
        guard let url =  URL.url() else {
             return completion(.failure(.wrongURL))
        }
          URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
            data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                return completion(.failure(.noData))
            }
            let statResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(StatResponse.self, from: data)
            if let statResponse = statResponse {
                completion(.success(statResponse.items))
                } else {
                    return completion(.failure(.decodingError))
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
class StatsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published private var items: Items?
    var subCount: Double {
        guard let subscriberCount = items?.statistics.subscriberCount else {
            return 0
        }
        return subscriberCount
    }
    func fetchStats() {
        StatService().getStats {
            result in switch result {
            case .success(let Items):
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.items = Items
                }
            case .failure(_ ):
                print("fail")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea what is going wrong, it gives 0 as the result. I tried various things like `self.items?.statistics = Items.statistics` instead of `self.items = Items` because I'm trying to get the data I'm trying to fetch is under statistics but it also didn't work and got an error saying "Value of optional type 'Stats?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'Stats'" and I don't know what to do, I can fetch non-nested objects pretty easily in Swift but I can't nested ones. I'm kind of a beginner to both Swift and programming in general so if that's a stupid question sorry for taking your time.

Comment: Don't use `try?` when decoding json downloaded from an external resource, use `try` with a `do/catch` and add a `print(error)`in the catch.

Comment: As said my Joakim Danielson: `try?` means: "If there is an error that would have been catchable and might have given specific information about why it fails that could help debug and fix the issue, I don't care about it." Use a `do`/`catch` and print the error. For instance, it might leads to use `let items: [Items]` instead of `let items: Items`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error on your model classes, the `items` property is an array, and you are trying to decode it as an object, change `StatResponse` to:

```
struct StatResponse: Decodable {
    let items: [Items]
}
```

Also change the `subscriberCount` to String on the `Stats` struct:

```
struct Stats: Decodable {
    let subscriberCount: String
}
```

Then you will have to change the way you are accessing the data, because now you're accessing an array. You can use the `first` property of an array which will return the first element of and array like this:

```
if let item = statResponse.items.first {
    completion(.success(item))
} else {
    return completion(.failure(.decodingError))
}
```

Comment: You didn't test this did you?

Comment: It gives an error saying "Instance member 'items' cannot be used on type 'StatResponse'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?" on `if let statResponse = StatResponse.items.first`

Comment: Well you fixed it now :) @Ckatalay, it is a spelling error on your part, it should be statResponse.items with a lowercase s